# Making assertions about elements in an Iterable

Tags: java, google-truth

I have a list of objects and I would like to make Truth-style assertions about the objects themselves, but I don't see any reasonable way to express anything more complex than equality assertions. I'm envisioning something like:

```
assertThat(list).containsElementThat().matches("Foo .* Bar");
```

Assuming that this isn't available in Truth, what's the most Truth-y way to express something like this? If I knew which position in the list I was looking I could say something like:

```
assertThat(list).hasSize(Math.max(list.size(), i));
assertThat(list.get(i)).matches("Foo .* Bar");
```

But (in addition to being somewhat hacky) that only works if I know `i` in advance, and doesn't work for arbitrary iterables. Is there any solution better than just doing this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give [`com.google.common.truth.Correspondence`](https://github.com/google/truth/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/common/truth/Correspondence.java) a try.

```java
public class MatchesCorrespondence<A> extends Correspondence<A, String> {
     @Override
     public boolean compare(@Nullable A actual, @Nullable String expected) {
         return actual != null && actual.toString().matches(expected);
     }

     // other overrides
}
```

Then you can assert like that:

```java
assertThat(list)
  .comparingElementsUsing(new MatchesCorrespondence<>())
  .contains("Foo .* Bar");
```

Comment: Oh interesting, I'd not seen the `Correspondence` before! This still seems odd though; for instance the imaginary `assertThat(list).containsElementThat().hasLength(5)` would become `assertThat(list).comparingElementsUsing(stringLengthCorrespondence).contains(5)` which is rather difficult to parse. Admittedly it's still much better than re-implementing everything yourself.

Comment: @dimo414 that's true. but you also can try to make a pull request to make things better :)

Comment: Never fear, that's my plan :) just trying to understand the state of the world before I do so.